# JPA - downcast entity and update it

Tags: jpa

I have an entity A and an entity B that extends A.
let's say A is a basic profile and B is a more complete one.
I look up in the bd to find A and I have to cast it in B to be able to get the more advanced profile.

I've tried to downcast but then JPA complains about detached entity.
I've tried to use a constructor in B that takes A in arguments, but still JPA complains.

I'm trying to find more information about it withtout that many success.

A and B are in 2 different tables, but when I create B directly everything is fine (B and A having the same id in their own table)

Any idea how I can get a A and convert it in B and get JPA to work as expected ?

Thanks !

Comment: post your classes. post error messages+stack races+persistence code ... rather than "JPA complains about detached entity" because "JPA" doesn't do anything, your JPA provider (which one?) does that.

Comment: This doesn't sound like a JPA issue as if you have/create an instance of A, it is NOT an instance of B.  These are java objects, and you need to create an new instance of B with the data you want to persist, and will likely need to remove the A instance from the database first.

Comment: You re right .. I thought I could down-cast it to B as it s an extended class, but seems like the only way I could achieve that was to create a new B with A as parameter, sets back my properties and then persist B